# install Oracle Weblogic failed

Tags: java, weblogic

I want to install Weblogic  but I m getting the error as  bellow :

Launcher log file is C:users....OraInstall2019...

Extracting files .... self extraction to C:\Users..... orc.....tmp failed.

press any key to exit

- I copied the file fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar  to the folder C:\temp
- I run the command : C:\ java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar  as Administrator
- the variable path is defined for JDK 1.8 that is already installed

and in the log file :

2019-01-17 10:34:26,610 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Launcher log file is C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2019-01-17_10-34-26AM\launcher2019-01-17_10-34-26AM.log.
2019-01-17 10:34:26,778 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting to C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl6458407520557089219.tmp.
2019-01-17 10:34:26,784 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting files...
2019-01-17 10:34:28,120 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Self extraction to C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl6458407520557089219.tmp failed.

any help please ?

Comment: Check diskspace on C:, download again the archive (Generic install). Also set JAVA_HOME variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem:
I run the command : C:\ java -jar fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar  from my JDK folder .